# Methods of enumeration(counting techniques)

Tags: combinatorics

"Ten children are to be grouped into two clubs, says the lions and the tigers, five in each club. Each club is then to elect a president and secretary. In how many ways can this be done?"

The answer key says 100,800. I can't find ways to solve this. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label the kiddos as: $1,2,3,\ldots , 9,10$. 
${10 \choose 5}$ is the number of ways to have two clubs of $5$ people in each club. This is because there are ${10\choose 5}$ many $5-$element subsets of $10$. Each $5$-element subset divides $10$ into two groups, the $5$-element subset and its complement in $\{1,2,\ldots 10\}$. Each club has $5$ choices for the president and $4$ choices for the secretary, after the president has been chosen. Hence $${10\choose 5}\cdot (5\cdot 4)\cdot (5\cdot 4)=100,800$$

is the number of ways this can be done.